# How do I increase virtual ram memory

Tags: memory, virtual-memory

I have a MacBook Air, but it only has 8GB of RAM. I need more than that for some apps, so I want more virtual RAM (I know it's not as fast as physical RAM, but it will be very useful) and I want to know how to increase virtual RAM on Mac OS 13 (Ventura).

Comment: In Mac OS 13 (Ventura), the system automatically manages the virtual RAM, also known as swap space. As such, there's no manual way to increase it. To better manage memory, monitor and limit high-memory usage applications through the Activity Monitor.

Comment: Virtual RAM, while providing a buffer when physical RAM is exhausted, operates at a slower pace as it uses storage drive space. Therefore, managing physical RAM efficiently is usually more effective than relying on virtual RAM.